# C++ – Trying to write files

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, file, filestream

I'm doing thenewboston tutorials for C++ and have just done a tutorial on file handling. My code looked exactly the same as his but the build failed. I think it might be because I'm on a mac and I think that might be the problem.
Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#inlcude <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    ofstream buckyFile;
    buckyFile.open("tuna.txt");

    buckyFile << "I love tuna and tuna loves me!\n";
    buckyFile.close();

}
```

Hope you can help.

Comment: _Always_ read the error messages! They often give you very good and sometimes very clear hints.

Comment: [We close all the typo questions as too localized.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167342/close-all-the-typo-questions)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the syntax highlighting makes clear, you have misspelt `include`:

```
#include <fstream>
```

Comment: i feel like such an idiot lol.......

Comment: @Dan299 Oh well, it happens to everybody. Don't forget to accept an answer!

Answer (score 2):

Include filestream  correctly and compile. It's nothing todo with MAC

```
#include <fstream>
```